# Vertical-alignment problems in IE using wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

I'm building out a blog category page in Wordpress and the design I have isn't working in Internet Explorer.

I'm trying to get text to center vertically in a div. I used some css styles to get it to work before on a different site, but now that I'm trying to use the same css in a Wordpress site, it's not working.

The css is:

```
div#linkwrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    line-height: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    color:transparent;
}

div#linkwrap span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

And the html is

```
<div id="linkwrap">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

You can view the page in Firefox, http://mbigelowphotographer.com/category/blog/ and it works properly. But in Internet Explorer the text doesn't center. I tested this same thing at http://andrewchambersdesign.co/test/ and it works. But for some reason when I implemented on the Wordpress site, no go.

Please any help is appreciated. Whether its a solution to this or just an easier way to achieve the same effect. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks exactly the same for me in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  There's nothing special about WordPress when it comes to CSS. It's just another website...Also, the code you posted above (CSS) doesn't exist anywhere in the first site you linked to.

Comment: try changing your span element to <div>
  <span style="position: absolute; padding-top:1px;"> some text </span>
</div>

Comment: rnevius, the code was in the stylesheet linked to that page. It is a lengthy stylesheet, I do need to learn how to organize it better.

Comment: I'm using Chrome's IE on Chrome extension to test it because I only have a Mac. But I just went and checked, and it is working now. Last night it did not look correct. I had cleared my cache but maybe the extension just wasn't working right at the time. So yeah, I guess it does work in all IE's except for 7. Any thoughts on what that problem might be?

Bradley Wilson, thank you for the suggestion. rnevius, thanks for checking it in your browsers and looking into it.